# Fastest way read single line in giant file

Tags: file, sed, line

So I have a website and I need to access a single line (line number is known) in a giant text file (~2GB).

I came to the conclusion that

> system_exec("sed -n 3p << /file/whatever.txt");

in PHP is the most efficient way.

But I don't feel very comfortable using it, it seems like a bad hack and insecure. Is it really ok to use it? Is this somehow possible without a PHP framework around? Or are there more efficient ways to do this?

Comment: if its efficient in php, then why not from shell?

Comment: The most efficient thing would be to preprocess the file so that all of its lines are the same length and just seek to the desired location.  If that's not possible, preprocess the file and record the start positions of each line.  Either way, you need to specify the problem further.  (Are you only searching once, or will you do this multiple times.?)

Comment: This access will happen very often, that's why it needs to be efficient. Preprocessing the file is not really possible because the content is dynamic and changes from time to time. Recording the start position of each line would be possible but I can smell the errors just yet due to the dynamic content. Or do you have good experience with this?

Comment: Do you generate the content?  Record the line start positions.  If not, sed -n is close to the best you can do.  If you can embed comments in the text file with line numbers, you could do a simple binary search in the file, seeking nearby for a newline and reading the comment for the current position.

Comment: If you are generating the content, truly the easiest thing to do would be to impose a fixed line length (say 120 chars) and pad everything with whitespace to match that.  You can then seek to the desired position.

Comment: I guess I will play around with the fixed line length for a bit, doesn't sound like the worst idea. Is seeking much more efficient than sed? Just for the sake of knowledge.

Comment: You're using the wrong tool for the job. Use a database.

Comment: saying that a this is the wrong tools is not a reply to the request and also it depend on context even if a DB could solve THIS problem faster (and maybe the good tools) there are other point arount this that can change the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are various ways you can offset into file, along with some crude benchmarks.

I created a text file with 90M lines. Each line contained 'something#####', though the numbers don't match up with the actual row (to make creating the sample data faster).

```
$ wc bigfile.txt
90000000 90000000 1340001000 bigfile.txt

$ ls -lrth bigfile.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 admin  wheel   1.2G Mar  8 09:37 bigfile.txt
```

These benchmarks were performed on a 1.3GHz i5, 4GB RAM, MacBook Air (11-inch, Mid 2013) running OS 10.10.2.

First up, is `awk`. I really expected better.

```
$ time awk 'NR == 10000000{print;exit}' bigfile.txt
something99999

real    0m12.716s
user    0m12.529s
sys     0m0.117s
```

`tail` performed a little better, though still quite slow.

```
$ time tail -n +10000000 bigfile.txt | head -n 1
something99999

real    0m10.393s
user    0m10.311s
sys     0m0.066s
```

As you found out, `sed` way outperforms the other contenders so far, for some reason. Though, still unacceptably slow.

```
$ time sed -n '10000000{p;q;}' bigfile.txt
something99999

real    0m3.846s
user    0m3.772s
sys     0m0.053s
```

If you have regular data (same number of bytes per line or can deterministically count number of bytes per line), you can forgo reading the file altogether and directly offset into the file. This is the fastest option, but also the most restrictive in terms of data format. This is what William Pursell was getting at when he suggested padding your data to a fixed size.

```
$ time tail -c +10000000 bigfile.txt | head -n 1
thing71851

real    0m0.020s
user    0m0.011s
sys     0m0.006s
```

However, if you have a 2G text file, you should consider using a proper database.

```
$ time sqlite3 bigfile.db << EOF
> create table bigdb(data text);
> .import bigfile.txt bigdb
> EOF

real    3m16.650s
user    3m3.703s
sys     0m4.221s

$ ls -lrth bigfile.db
-rw-r--r--  1 admin  wheel   1.9G Mar  8 10:16 bigfile.db
```

Now that you have a database, you should be able to get blazing fast speeds right? Only if you use it properly. `OFFSET` (the first argument to `LIMIT`) is notorious for being ridiculously slow, and should be avoided.

```
$ time sqlite3 bigfile.db <<< 'select * from bigdb limit 10000000-1, 1;'
something99999

real    0m2.156s
user    0m0.688s
sys     0m0.440s
```

You should have a proper primary key, or use sqlite's handy internal column `ROWID` to get optimal performance.

```
$ time sqlite3 bigfile.db <<< 'select * from bigdb where ROWID == 10000000;'
something99999

real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.005s
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Problem is that I'm not allowed to use real databases due to system restriction (better don't ask). But now that I see the difference between using sed and offset I think my decision is made :)

Answer (score 2):

With little modification fastest way for printing single line in giant file is using also q (Quit) command

```
sed -n '3{p;q}' yourFile
```

This will print 3rd line, and sed will stop working then.

Answer (score 0):

On my system I have a totaly different conclusion
Environnement: AIX under KSH

```
FileName=listOfBig.txt
# ls -l -> 239.070.208 bytes
# wc -l listOfBig.txt | read FileSize Ignore
FileSize=638976

# take a portion of 8 lines at 1000 lines of the end
LineToStart=$(( ${FileSize} - 1024 ))
LineToTake=8
LineToStop=$(( ${LineToStart} + ${LineToTake} - 1 ))

time sed -n "${LineToStart},${LineToStop} p;${LineToStop} q" ${FileName} >/dev/null
real    0m1.49s
user    0m0.45s
sys     0m0.41s

time sed "${LineToStart},${LineToStop} !d;${LineToStop} q" ${FileName} >/dev/null
real    0m1.51s
user    0m0.45s
sys     0m0.42s

time tail -n +${LineToStart} ${FileName} | head -${LineToTake} >/dev/null
real    0m0.34s
user    0m0.00s
sys     0m0.00s

time head -${LineToStop}  ${FileName} | tail -${LineToTake} >/dev/null
real    0m0.84s
user    0m0.75s
sys     0m0.23s
```

There is certainly a small advantage to second and following test that 1st (cache, ...) but not very different

So, in this test, sed is lot slower (not a GNU version of tools like on linux).

There is another issue that is not explain in case of huge file (could happend on small but rarely) is the problem of piped stream if file is changing (often the case on log). I have once the problem and should create a temporary file (unhoppefully huge also) to treat the other request of the line if any.